# How to configure AWS Load Balancer use a specific machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket

We have a video meetings application that relies on a server using WebSockets.

The clients communicate with the server using WebSockets.

We would like to horizontally scale our app. So we have been thinking about using AWS Load Balancing.

Basically, our server app will be installed on several EC2 machines and users will be redirected to the machine with the lowest load.

The problem is that we have a specific requirement such that, the first user that connects to a meeting (machine), all the users connected to the same meeting should be forwarded to the same machine. So that our Server App can recognize all the participants to the same meeting.

So basically here is the process :

- First User connected to meeting A => Forward to the machine with the lowest load (let's call it : X)
- Second User connected to meeting A => Forward to machine X
- First User connected to meeting B => Forward to the machine with the lowest load (let's call it : Y)
- Second User connected to meeting B => Forward to machine Y
- etc.

Does anyone have an idea on how to configure AWS Load Balancer to work this way ?

Thanks.
Cheers,

Comment: This is a very broad question, and how you implement depends on the specifics of your application.  To give you some things to look at though... many folks like to use something like Redis to handle pub/sub for them.  That way, you can scale your application servers normally, while still handling a centralized place for messaging.  Others just use a normal database, such as PostgreSQL.  Depending on the kinds of data you want to share and with what "rooms", you might find partitioning the data to be the best, where some room key deterministically indicates what server to use.

Comment: (continued...) But yes, there are lots of ways to do this, within AWS or otherwise.  I've even used S3 as sort of a reliable data store for routing folks around.  (This works, as long as you're okay with the ~500ms sync latency... not good for all applications!)

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem while trying to migrate a legacy windows application onto AWS. I could not make use of AWS resources to get this sorted out but I figured another way of doing it.

I have used the opensource HAProxy's sticky tables to control the server allocation (https://www.haproxy.com/blog/introduction-to-haproxy-stick-tables/) . I had a use case where I had to direct all the requests from a particular IP address to the same server in an autoscaling group.

I setup a HAProxy server group within an ASG. Had an ELB in front of the HAProxy ASG and then the HAProxy servers route traffic to the appropriate backend server. The setup is a lot more complicated that it sounds but it served the purpose and is still running perfectly without any problem. It's been 3 years since I set that up.

If this is something that can help you, let me know. Happy to share the setup details and other things that might help you.